# How to change the browser screen size on Jenkins?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

Due to screen size no such element displayed and my test cases are failed but executing from selenium IDE on my local all test cases successfully executed without fail. When I executing browsers are not open but in my extent test report I got the screenshot of every pages but screen size has not changed but in my code i have not mention headless mode but while setting up my Jenkins configuration I have added below lines in the Jenkins file which I referred from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuMrEDA8cAI&t=860s

'''-Xrs -Xms3g -Xmx3g -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\tools\Jenkins\tmp\ -Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=Asia/Kolkata -Duser.timezone=Asia/Kolkata -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "C:\tools\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="C:\tools\Jenkins\war" --pluginroot="C:\tools\Jenkins\plugins"'''

This is my code:

```
'''if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("window-size=1936, 1048");
        setDriver(new ChromeDriver(options));
                    getDriver().manage().window().maximize();

            // Set the size again to ensure consistency
            Dimension newSize = new Dimension(1936, 1048);
            getDriver().manage().window().setSize(newSize);

            System.out.println("Current screen size :" + 
            getDriver().manage().window().getSize());`your text'''
```

But in the Jenkins console:
**Current screen size :(1044, 788)**

I am expected to increase the screen size of the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use in my project.

```
int w = 1920;
int h = 1080;
...
options.addArguments("--window-size=" + w + "," + h);
```

Note that this will only work for headless execution, for headless you need to add:

```
options.addArguments("--headless");
```

If you are not running on headless, it will use your machine's resolution by default.

Comment: I have tried  options.addArguments("--headless"); the screen size has changed but the error is displayed.

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of all [Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: (//span[text()='Rapido'])[1]'] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: since your question is focused more on the screen size. I think this is already answered. Probably a new question for your issue on element not located. Please raise a new question then add as much detail as you can. such as how did you locate your element, sample HTML, does it have iFrames, etc

Comment: Thanks @PQ Co. The screen size issue resolved.  I will create a new question for no such element and timeout exception while running headless on java selenium web driver.